# Where is the location of the fcntl module of python?

Tags: python, tomcat, jython

I'm on unix but I can't find the location of the fcntl module. I'm using Jython in my web development, and the existing program that I'm modifying needs that module. Can you give me a way to import it or for my code to be able to use this module? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fcntl` is a built-in module. It's not written in Python, but in C. Unfortunately, it hasn't been ported to Java, and according to [this bug report](http://bugs.jython.org/issue1074), it's unlikely that it ever will be.

To answer your question: it's in the CPython source, [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/cb464f8fb3a1/Modules/fcntlmodule.c).

The problem is that fcntl is Unix-specific; your program was not portable from the start. Java is pretty strictly platform-independent, and (as the Jython developers imply in that bug report) some low-level things aren't possible. You can search about the particular functions you need — you'll might a better chance of getting that to work than the whole module – but I'd recommend looking for some way around the problem rather than trying to get fcntl to work in Java.

I hope you can find an alternative solution.

Comment: Thanks Petr! Is there an alternative for this? The program needs the function of the fcntl module called lockf. Is there any library that I can use to achieve the same effect?

Comment: I'm, unfortunately, not an expert on Java/Jython. Is there any chance this program can go without this functionality?

Comment: Do you know what the fcntl.lockf() function does? Can you give me an overview to what it is used to?

Comment: It locks a part of a file – see the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.lockf).