# Python - Cannot Find fcntl.FNDELAY

Tags: linux, python-2.7

I want to use the following code that I found in 15+ year old book on Python (we currently use Python 2.7 because of back-porting issues but will go to Python 3. for the next major project).

```
import os, popen2, fcntl, select

def makeNonBlocking(fd):
    fl = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
    try:
        fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, fl | fcntl.O_NDELAY)
    except AttributeError:
        fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, fl | fcntl.FNDELAY)
```

The issue is that it cannot find the attribute 'fcntl.FNDELAY'. Googling for over an hour has got me no further. Replacing the code with a NULL statement confirms that it is finding fcntl.O_NDELAY

The OS is Linux Mint 17.3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the location of the fcntl module of python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723571/where-is-the-location-of-the-fcntl-module-of-python)

Answer (score 0):

Quick googling suggests you are probably looking for [`os.O_NDELAY`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.O_NDELAY) which was at some point also know as `os.FNDELAY`.

Comment: See the try/except near the beginning of https://bugs.python.org/file2321/utils.py